# jQuery Ajax Call Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a dropdown menu that when selected the following code executes. This works perfectly 100% of the time on Chrome on my personal computer, however, I find on other people's computers (who are using Chrome or Firefox, etc) the code can be temperamental. I'm also finding issues on Firefox on my own computer.

Basically the code has three ajax calls, the first being to render a logo on the page, the second to render a html table and the third updates a chartjs canvas.

One specific issue on Firefox is that the page items only render every second time I change a selection on the dropdown menu. Other reported issues are that sometimes specific dropdown selections don't render any items, however there is nothing wrong with the dropdown code as it works perfectly fine for other users.

I'm no expert on jQuery however I've used this structure for Ajax calls on other pages and have had no issues at all. Is there some core issues in the code below which may be introducing these issues?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var valueCheck;

  jQuery('#afl_team').on('change', function() {
    afl_team = $('#afl_team').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: {
        action: 'call_team_logo',
        afl_team: afl_team,
      },
      success: function(output) {
        jQuery('#team_logo').html(output);
      }
    });

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: {
        action: 'call_ruck_team_stats',
        afl_team: afl_team,
      },
      success: function(output) {
        jQuery('#ruck_stats').html(output);
      }
    });

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        action: 'call_ruck_contests',
        afl_team: afl_team,
      },
      success: function updateruckChart(output) {
        ruckChart.data.datasets = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < output[0].length; i++) {
          ruckChart.data.datasets.push({
            label: output[0][i],
            backgroundColor: output[2][i],
            borderColor: output[2][i],
            data: output[1][i]
          });
          ruckChart.update();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

----------- UPDATE -----------

Based on the comments to this post I consolidated part of this code to return json from less AJAX calls but I am still having problems. Using the developer tool in firefox I've noticed that there is no issue with the Ajax call firing, it's just 80% of the time it returns a result and the other 20% of the time it doesnt.

When it doesn't return anything the developer tool indicates type as xml but when it works successfully it indicates html. There is no consistency to when it will work or when it won't work.

My Ajax Call Javascript in it's entirety for the page is as per below. I've tried deleting scripts and re-running but I still get intermittent success.

Temp page for reference is [here](http://dailyfantasysportsaustralia.com/afl-ruck-analysis-temporary/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery('#afl_team').on( 'change', function () {
         afl_team = $('#afl_team').val();
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        dataType: "html",               //POSSIBLY DELETE
       data: {
            action: 'call_team_logo',
            afl_team: afl_team,
        },
         success:function(output){
            jQuery('#team_logo').html( output );
         }
     });
    });
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery('#afl_team,#afl_opponent').on( 'change', function () {
         afl_team = $('#afl_team').val();
         afl_opponent = $('#afl_opponent').val();
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'call_ruck_last_time',
            afl_team: afl_team,
            afl_opponent: afl_opponent,
        },
         success:function(output){
             jQuery('#ruck_last_time').html( output );
         }
     });
    }).change();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery('#afl_team').on( 'change', function () {
         afl_team = $('#afl_team').val();
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        dataType: "json", 
        data: {
            action: 'call_ruck_team_stats_json',
            afl_team: afl_team,
        },
         success:function(output){
            var myJSON = output[0];
            var myJSON2 = output[1];
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myJSON[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.
        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myJSON[i][col[j]];
            }
        }
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("teamSummary");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myJSON2.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myJSON2[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.
        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < myJSON2.length; i++) {
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myJSON2[i][col[j]];
            }
        }
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("opponentSummary");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
            ruckChart.data.datasets = [];
            for (var i=0; i<output[2].length; i++) {
                ruckChart.data.datasets.push({
                  label: output[2][i],
                  backgroundColor: output[4][i],
                  borderColor: output[4][i],
                  data: output[3][i]
                });
         ruckChart.update();
            }
            }   // THIS BRACKET CLOSES SUCCESS FUNCTION
     });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Whenever I need multiple ajax calls on my site, I try and group them into one and have the server code send one answer, with its different response elements separated by a delimiter (like ^°^ or something improbable). Then it's just a question of splitting the answer and you've got yourself an array containing the results you want. 3 concurrent ajax calls, I've found, is asking for trouble.

Comment: I like the idea of consolidating my three php files into one and having one ajax call, however I'm not sure how I return 2 html tables and the json array and then split them to render them on the page. Are you able to provide a reference link or similar to how I might go about doing this?

Comment: You shouldn't return back the HTML, return an object/Array and build your html on the Front-end instead.

Comment: Ok, so return a json array and then build front end html table. I've got no issues returning the json array but will need to look into how to create the front end html table. Appreciating the feedback.

Comment: I've re-structured as recommended with json and then front-end html but it still doesn't help. I'm noticing that the Ajax calls are being activated (I can see that in developer), it's just some times they return a result and others times they don't, even with consistent parameters. I've updated the question to give more detail, would appreciate any help.